# Subproject module can't resolve it's own dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the structure:

```
rootproject
    - module-1
    - subproject
        - module-1-1
        - module-1-2
```

`module-1` depends on `module-1-1` and `module-1-2`

`module-1-2` depends on `module-1-1`

When I sync `subproject` as separate project, everything works fine

When I trying to sync `rootproject`, `module-1` resolved its dependencies, but `module-1-2` can't find `module-1-1`

settings.gradle of rootproject

```
include ':subproject'
include ':subproject:module-1-1'
include ':subproject:module-1-2'
```

settings.gradle of subproject

```
include ':module-1-1'
include ':module-1-2'
```

build.gradle of module-1

```
implementation project(':subproject:module-1-1')
implementation project(':subproject:module-1-2')
```

build.gradle of module-1.2

```
implementation project(':module-1-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. Thats what I do:

settings.gradle of rootproject

```
project(':module-1-1').projectDir = new File('subproject/module-1-1')
project(':module-1-2').projectDir = new File('subproject/module-1-2')
```

build.gradle of module-1

```
implementation project(':module-1-1')
implementation project(':module-1-2')
```

Also you can go to File -> Project Structure -> Hit `Alt` + `Insert`-> Select **Import gradle project** and select your subproject folder. After that you can add subproject modules.